# MIPS return value from memory address

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to program in Assembly (MIPS) a function to return the max value of an array.

The C code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MaxAssembly(int *ptr, int num_elements); 

int main ( ) 
{ 
  int n=9; 
  int tab[] = {2, -8, 0, 25, 14, 2, 9, 15, -32}; 
  printf("The maximum is %d \n", MaxAssembly(tab,n));
```

`MaxAssembly`is the function I have to program in Assembly.

I'm not in the part to find the max. My problem in in reading the functions arguments. I have made this code to do some tests.

```
    .data

    .text
    .globl  MaxAssembly

MaxAssembly:
    add $9,$5,$zero
    move    $2,$9
    jr  $ra
```

Doing this code I can see that I'm reading the second function argument as expected. It's printed on the screen `The maximum is 9`
Changing the code to:

```
    .data

    .text
    .globl  MaxAssembly

MaxAssembly:
    move    $2,$4
    jr  $ra
```

I can see that it's reading the first argument of the function as a memory address and it's printed on the screen `The maximum is 2143429780`. So far is working as expected.

The problem is when I try to read the element stored at that memory address (the first element of the array). I'm getting one segmentation fault...
I'm doing this:

```
    .data

    .text
    .globl  MaxAssembly

MaxAssembly:
    lw      $16,0($4)
    move    $2,$16
    jr  $ra
```

What am I doing wrong? wasn't `lw`supposed to store at `$16` the first item of the array? Using `lb`is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `lw $s0, 0($a0)` will read a full word from the address in `$a0` to `$s0`. Unlike, lb, memory access via lw must use word-aligned addresses (i.e., two LSB are zero). I suspect that's where the problem occur.

Comment: Found the problem. Registers 16 to 23 are function registers and must be preserved. Used registers from 8 to 15 and all is function as expected :)

Comment: @Favolas Yes register 16-23 ($s0-$s7) should be preserved. This is why you'd normally use $t0-$t7 (registers 8-15). However this would not cause a lw to segfault. It would, however, cause (possible) problems for register $s0 if it was used. (But that problem would happen in the callee)